# Stream real time data from smart band/watch to computer via Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, data-transfer, streaming, smart-watches

**Description**: I have a smart wrist band ([link to Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FC49PSV)) which has Bluetooth connectivity. 
My goal is to read real time on my computer (running Ubuntu 18.04) some of the data that is tracked by the wearable device such as the HR or the number of steps. In other words, everytime the desired variable is recorded by the smart band it should also be displayed on my PC monitor.

**Question**: Unfortunately I am a beginner in this topic and I have no clue about how to do it and if it is even possible. As consequence I would like to ask if you are able to provide some links to possible solutions where I can get some inspiration from? It would be nice that the suggested solutions involved some open-source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a pretty standard Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) device so assuming the manufacturer hasn't done something strange (e.g. like fitbit) then you should be able to use any language that has BLE GATT support to connect to the device and then subscribe to the characteristics for each of the different data fields. For NodeJS there is the [noble](https://www.npmjs.com/package/noble) which is pretty for building this sort of thing.

There are mobile apps like the [nRF Connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp&hl=en_GB) that will let you interrogate the device and let you determine the UUIDs for the Service and Characteristics which will help get you started.